# @RequestBody not restricting to POJO type and BindingResult hasErrors always false

Tags: spring-boot

I was not experiencing this problem early in development but just noticed that this was happening when debugging another problem. This happens on all REST endpoints, but below is an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/editlisting")
public class EditParkingSpaceListingController {
@Autowired
ParkingSpaceRepository parkingSpaceRepository;
@Autowired
ParkingSpaceListingRepository parkingSpaceListingRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> editParking(@RequestBody ParkingSpaceListingClient pslc, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
// Code to save pslc data to database.
```

Now, if I send an HTTP request with the body as

```
{  }
```

I get a 200 response and when I check MongoDB, there is a new empty document in the collection. If I send an empty body with no brackets, as expected it will return 400. If I send a body with random garbage data that does not exist in the POJO, BindingResult does not seem to pick up the error and a new blank document is still created.

Comment: It return 400 as expected with spring boot 1.4.1, what's the exact spring boot version in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps for the input document validations:

(1) Add the `javax.validation` package constraints (like `@NotNull`, `@Size`, etc..) to your `ParkingSpaceListingClient` bean class.

(2) Add `@Validated annotation` to your controller method, to capture the validation errors into `BindingResult` object.

You can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) for more details on Input Validations.