# Spring REST Controller accepts arbitrary elements in request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, request

I am doing a PUT call to update an existing entity and send the following request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<campaign xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <aaaa>123</aaaa>
</campaign>
```

Server responds with a 200 OK, although there is certainly no property "aaaa" in the POJO class to which the response is mapped. Debugging shows that a completly empty POJO instance is being passed to the controller.

How can I get Spring to complain about it? We had users that couldn't understand why an update didn't work and they simply misspelled a property-name - and didn't understand they made a mistake since they got a 200 OK.

Can I somehow use BindingResult for that? Changing my controller method to something like this doesn't work:

```
public RsCampaign updateCampaign(@Validated @RequestBody RsCampaign rsCampaign, BindingResult bindingResult, ...
```

Spring then complains with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
```

This question here is similar but doesn't help me: [@RequestBody not restricting to POJO type and BindingResult hasErrors always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456033/requestbody-not-restricting-to-pojo-type-and-bindingresult-haserrors-always-fal)

Comment: if the body is incorrect, shoulndn't the server simply return HTTP-400?

Comment: Yes, please! :)

Comment: Use `@Valid` instead of `@Validated` also each & every field in `RsCampaign` should contain validation annotations like `@NotEmpty` etc.

Comment: I still get the same exception (have swapped ´@Validated´ for ´@Valid´ and have annotated a field in RsCampaign with ´@NotEmpty´)